# IPC 4671 Via Types

Tags: pcb-fabrication, via

In Altium designer the via type can be declared as one of the follows:

[image]

I know about tenting. This is where a via is covered. This way it won't cut through the silk screen or solder mask. But why would a person ever need the other options tenting and covering, plugging, plugging and covering? Surely, just tenting should be enough. It will hide the via and prevent something from going it into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tenting (Type I and II):**
Tenting is the simplest of all via covering options. All tenting options have the major downside of possible entrapment of chemicals that may create long-term reliability issues. Also entrapped gas can burst open the tent due to expansion during the soldering process (can be avoided by tenting only one side of the via).

Depending on the type of solder mask used other problems may occur: The tent can collapse when the via hole is too big for the applied solder mask type. Or a very fluid solder mask can cause ugly "pimples" around the via hole.

The difference between Type I and II is that with Type II two (different type) solder mask layers are used to cover the hole for increased robustness.

**Via plugging (Type III and IV):**
Via plugging overcomes some of the downsides of via tenting: The hole openings are plugged with a non-conductive paste that is more robust than solder mask. But the issues of trapped chemicals and gas are still there. At least the problem of vias bursting open due to gas expansion can be avoided, if just one side of the via is plugged (as with tenting).

Also plugging is usually more suitable for bigger via holes compared to tenting. However, there is usually a minimum diameter requirement for plugging as opposed to tenting which can be applied to arbitrarily small via holes.

The difference between Type III and IV is that with Type IV there is  solder mask applied on top of the plugged via.

**Via Filling (Type V, VI and VII):**
With via filling the via is *completely* filled with non-conductive paste. This avoids all entrapment issues. The filled via may then be covered with solder mask (Type VI) or a flush and solderable surface finish (Type VII or "capped"). The main advantage of capped vias is their use as "Via-in-Pad": You can place a via directly in a pad without worrying about solder flowing through. This saves a lot of space in very dense designs or might even be a necessity to be able to fan-out packages like narrow pitch BGAs.

**Cost:**
Tenting is the cheapest type, as it causes practically no additional cost. I personally never used plugging, because if I already need to pay additional money I might as well go for the "best" option (filling). Also the PCB shops I'm usually working with are more used to via filling and have much more experience and process knowledge compared to plugging. So all things considered, filling might even be cheaper than plugging.

But all cost aspects may depend very heavily on the specific PCB shop you are using.

For further reading Multi-CB has a convenient overview on via types:
https://www.multi-circuit-boards.eu/en/pcb-design-aid/surface/via-covering.html

Comment: I thought the difference between type I and II was just that type II was done on both sides and type I on just top side but otherwise they were identical. Is this understanding incorrect ?

Comment: @quantum231 The small letters "a" and "b" distinguish between double and single sided. Type I and II are (slightly) different processes.

Answer (score 1):

BGA's need to have these options. There are a few other places that you might need these.

If you want to to via in pad, then you need plugging. BGA's with very small clearances (like 3mil) will also need special attention to vias to avoid wicking and breakage from thermal stress.

Here are some tradeoffs between filling and plugging.

[image]
Source: https://www.qualiecocircuits.com.au/via-tenting-filling-plugging.html

Comment: hmm, so far in the PCB learning experience, I have not used BGA package so I can see from your description why these different via types are so important